# Android Studio KMM Project with c/c++ module Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, cocoapods, kmm

We are trying to build a KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) app for ios and android. There are c/c++ modules included in this project.
At iOS build we are getting this error from a .h file:

```
error: use of '@import' when modules are disabled
```

In xcode this seems like an easy problem to fix, but in Android studio, we can't find a solution. I'm thinking this is a Podfile/.podspec issue, but I haven't been able to find any working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of :

```
@import MyModule;
```

just try :

```
#import <MyModule/MyModule.h>
```

Comment: Don't think thats possible in our case. This is a third-party ios library coming in through Cocoapods.

Comment: Ok, and you can't get a precompiled version of this third party dependency ? a xcframework for instance ?

Comment: Thanks for this. It set me in the right direction. We just went with a different library, that had the proper import type.